# Temperature of a Diamond in a Boiling Pot of Water

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Suppose I have a boiling pot of water (100 degrees C) and drop a diamond in. Does the diamond eventually reach 100 degrees C?

Since the diamond is a rigid structure, its molecules do not vibrate that much. Water molecules colliding with the diamond may just bounce off elastically without imparting any velocity to the particles of the diamond. Because temperature is related to average speed, I think the diamond could remain at a lower temperature than the water indefinitely.

Comment: Your reasoning for why the diamond might stay at a lower termperature does not make sense to me. Many things have rigid lattice structures, and yet they heat up when you drop them into water (try it with a coin!).

Comment: Yes I thought about that too, but I think diamonds are much harder than coins. And maybe there is a super-hard diamond which might exhibit the property of not being able to be heated.

Comment: Than you would be wrong. Diamond is a great conductor of heat, precisely because it is so rigid.

Comment: @JonCuster Would you elaborate? Why does rigidity allow it to be heated up? And if I had a super non-rigid object (maybe a sponge or something) could it be made non-heatable by increasing its sponginess?

Comment: Sounds like a HW question. Hint: "temperature is related to average speed" is incorrect. The average speed of the atoms in a crystal is zero (the atoms do not translate), so is the temperature zero?

Comment: @KevinVW I thought about that, but I don't think I was able to come to a sensible resolution. This isn't a HW question so you don't need to feel bad about giving me "the answer"

Comment: Maybe one answer is that heat means something different in solids than in gasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that to figure out how quickly an object heats up, you need the ratio of two quantities - the thermal conductivity, and the volumetric heat capacity. If the former is large AND the latter is small, you get an object that will quickly take up the heat of its surroundings.

This parameter is known as the "thermal diffusivity"

$$\alpha = \frac{k}{\rho c_p}$$

And it shows up in the thermal diffusion equation:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha \nabla^2 T$$

Now the "stiffness" of diamond translates into a high bulk modulus: that is, a lot of force is needed to create a small displacement. For a sound wave, this means that the speed of sound will be very high since it is given by

$$c = \sqrt{\frac{K}{\rho}}$$

The higher the bulk modulus K, the higher the speed.

Finally, if you consider that thermal transport is really the transport of phonons through the solid, then clearly a higher modulus will result in better heat transport.

Putting it all together, diamond (with high speed of sound, low density, and low heat capacity) is an excellent heat conductor - and will quickly approach the temperature of its surroundings. Mathematically it will never "get there" since the solution to the heat diffusion equation is asymptotic. But since the cup of boiling water will itself cool down, there will actually be a time when the diamond is hotter than the surroundings. Which means there must be a point where the (mean) temperature of the diamond is equal to the (mean) temperature of the water.

Comment: Is the diffusion equation itself derived from statistical models of particle motion? Or is it empirical law?

Comment: Diffusion equation can be derived from statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 5):

Practically speaking, diamond has the highest thermal conductivity of any "reasonable" material, about 5 times greater than copper. Additionally, its specific heat is about 30% greater than copper or brass, but about 10% that of water. As a result, a diamond will heat up faster than just about anything else, particularly when immersed in a liquid like water with a high specific heat and which is boiling (produces strong convective currents to apply heat to the surface.

Comment: Could you explain where my reasoning went wrong?

Comment: Temperature is not the amplitude of the thermal motion of the constituent atoms, rather, it is the average kinetic energy of that motion. So two things happen in a "rigid" material. First, the natural frequency of the lattice goes up, which means the atoms vibrate faster, although at a smaller amplitude. Second, the rigidity allows faster propagation of thermal excitation through the material.

Comment: Would that imply that a squishy material heats up slower than a crystal because it would take time for the atomic motions to propagate into the center of the material?

Comment: It gets complicated, but the simple answer is no. For example, about the best commercially-available thermal compound you can buy for ensuring good thermal performance of CPU heat sinks is a paste made up of liquid silicone and diamond dust.